# MS DOS Installation

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

I have an Intel Macbook and I want to install MS DOS (I'm using Virtualbox). A couple of questions:

1. I found sealed versions of MS DOS on ebay however it says "For Distribution only with a new PC": will I be able to use it and do an installation from scratch?
2. There is a site (winworldpc.com) that offers a download, is this safe and legal?
3. Generally from an installation of DOS via Virtualbox is there any risk for the Mac in case of viruses or other malware?

thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: Have you considered [FreeDOS](https://www.freedos.org)? There is an [VirtualBox installation guide](http://wiki.freedos.org/wiki/index.php/VirtualBox).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have and tried it but a piece of software i want to run does not work properly.

Comment: First, this question is three questions. A question shouldn’t have more than one answer. The answers are: 1) legally you don’t own the rights to run this because you did not aquire it with a new PC, you bought off someone who didn’t legally have the right to sell it without the PC it came with. 2) I can’t speak to the safety of the site, it’s likely an illegal copy or unsafe. 3) should be generally safe

Comment: There is also the free DOSBox and DOSBox-x that allows you to run DOS programs on M1 **and** Intel Macs. I use the latter to play a couple of old DOS games I bought ages ago...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, very much appreciated. If I purchase installation disks with the "For Distribution only with a new PC" note, will the installation still work or does the |distribution only with a new PC" mean they are missing something (eg. a serial number), thanks again.

Comment: @PeterKKB I answered your question on “distributed with new pc” in my last comment. It just means “this is msdos is licensed for use only on the computer it was provided. You are not permitted to use this msdos with a different computer  or in a virtualization environment”

Answer (score 1):

Technically, any copy of MS-DOS should work (even if [FreeDOS](https://www.freedos.org) is usually the better option because it avoids any potential legal issues).

As far as virii are concerned, it's highly unlikely that a virus written for MS-DOS will have the capability to tunnel through VirtualBox and infect the host OS.